# Ошибка при локальных запросах CORS policy

Tags: node.js, http, cors

Проблема стандартная, но решений перепробовал кучу.
Возможно где-то что-то не так делаю отсюда и проблема.

**К сути:**

Самый примитивный сервер (даже не обрабатывает ничего).

```
const http = require('http');

const server = http.createServer((request, response) => {
  response.end()
})

server.listen(4000);
```

**Я делаю запрос на него:**

```
 axios.post('http://localhost:4000/')
  .then((response) => console.log(response))
  .catch((error) => console.log(error)
  );
```

**В и тоге получаю**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Добавлял всякое разное в **.htaccess** ничего не помогает.

Как лечить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте добавить в ответ сервера соответствующий заголовок

```
const http = require('http');

const server = http.createServer((request, response) => {
  response.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  response.end()
})

server.listen(4000);
```

Comment: Большое спасибо) хоть кто-то мне внес ясность)